# windows batch splitting file in to two based on conditions

Tags: batch-file

I have a file where the starting words are any case "add" "changeprop" OR "anyother"
I am trying to read such file and based on if conditions pushing that specific line to add.txt , changeprop.txt and errorrecords.txt

Having hard time at the substing place as the variable is not holding the line value  and i am unable to finish this job :(

```
set "File=.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\All_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File%"') do (
 SET eachline=%%a
  IF "%eachline:~0,3%"=="ADD" ( echo "%eachline%">>.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\ADD_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt)
  IF "%eachline:~0,3%"=="and" ( echo "%eachline%">>.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\ADD_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt)
  IF "%eachline:~0,10%"=="CHANGEPROP"  ( echo "%eachline%">>.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\CHANGEPROP_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt)
  IF "%eachline:~0,10%"=="changeprop"  ( echo "%eachline%">>.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\CHANGEPROP_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt)
 REM pause
)
```

I feel like losing the mind - after trying call / internal block / differnt ways of using a variable . nothing is holding value of the just read line for substring compare place. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using multiple if statements with one command each, you do not need to parenthesize the `echo` commands. Your problem however is actually the fact that you `enabledelayedexpansion` without actually using it. You can also simply use `/i` switch with the `if` statement to be case insensitive, so no need to check each line twice for a match. Lastly, I would use `%~dp0` instead of `.\`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "File=%~dp0WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\All_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File%"') do (
 set "eachline=%%a"
  if /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD" echo "!eachline!">>"%~dp0WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\ADD_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
  if /i "!eachline:~0,10!" == "CHANGEPROP" echo "!eachline!">>"%~dp0WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\CHANGEPROP_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
)
```

Comment: Hi Garard-Barnard,     i sincerely thank you and your time helping me out . it worked exactly your code. Namaste.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the same, is less error-prone and probably a lot faster:

```
@echo off
set "File=.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\All_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
Type "%File%" |findstr /bi "add" > .\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\ADD_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt
Type "%File%" |findstr /bi "changeprop" >.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\CHANGEPROP_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt
```

Comment: @ stephen Once my main objective is achieved - i will use this findstr approach . Now i am dealing with multiple if else condition situation. The reason i am going with if approach is if i dont have any match then i want to push that line to a errorcatch file .

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('TYPE "c:\Inputfile.txt"') DO (
 SET "eachline=%%a"
    IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD " (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\ADD.txt")
    ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,9!" == "ADDINSERT" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\ADDINSERT.txt")
        ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "MOV" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\MOVE.txt")
            ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,6!" == "INSERT" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\INSERT.txt")
                ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,10!" == "CHANGEPROP" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\CHANGEPRO.txt")
                            ELSE (ECHO !eachline!>>"OTHER.txt"))))))

Comment: I've seen your [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229655/multiple-if-else-conditions-issue) and already answered it. If you want to stay with `if` statements, your first should use `"!eachline:~0,4!"` (`~0,3` will never match the four chars `ADD<space>`)