# multiple IF else conditions issue

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have an issue where I want to segregate / split file based on search item into multiple files.
if I see `add` I want to put that line to `addfile`.
similar to `changeprop`, insert and if I cannot find any match then to `otherfile`.   I'm unable to process the `if else` conditions.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('TYPE "%File%"') DO (
    SET "eachline=%%a"
    IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD " (ECHO !eachline!>>"%ADDActionScriptsMergedFile%")
    ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,9!" == "ADDINSERT" (ECHO !eachline!>>"%ADDINSERTActionScriptsMergedFile%")
        ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "MOV" (ECHO !eachline!>>"%MOVEActionScriptsMergedFile%")
            ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,6!" == "INSERT" (ECHO !eachline!>>"%INSERTPROPActionScriptsMergedFile%")
                ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,10!" == "CHANGEPROP" (ECHO !eachline!>>"%CHANGEPROPActionScriptsMergedFile%")
                    ELSE (ECHO !eachline!>>"%OTHERPROPActionScriptsMergedFile%")
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('TYPE "c:\Inputfile.txt"') DO (
 SET "eachline=%%a"
    IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD " (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\ADD.txt")
    ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,9!" == "ADDINSERT" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\ADDINSERT.txt")
        ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "MOV" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\MOVE.txt")
            ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,6!" == "INSERT" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\INSERT.txt")
                ELSE ( IF /i "!eachline:~0,10!" == "CHANGEPROP" (ECHO !eachline!>>"c:\CHANGEPRO.txt")
                            ELSE (ECHO !eachline!>>"OTHER.txt")
)))))

Comment: This latest comment is code with no variables .. for easiness. if any match found then push line to that specific file. if no match then push that line to a OTHER.txt file.

Comment: `ELSE (` should be on the same line as the closing `IF` parentheses, i.e. `)ELSE ` or `) ELSE`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. It is based on my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60216585/2152082), but changed a bit to avoid writing the same code several times (two times was ok, but now, that it's 5 (or maybe even more), it makes sense to use a `for` loop):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "File=.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\All_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
set "Dest=.\WorkFlow_Action_Script_Merged_Folder\@_WorkFlows_Merged_File.txt"
for %%a in ("Add " Addinsert Mov Insert Changeprop) do (
  type "%File%" | findstr /bic:"%%~a" > "%Dest:@=%%~a%"
)
type "%File%" |findstr /bivc:"Addinsert" /bivc:"Mov" /bivc:"Insert" /bivc:"Changeprop" /bivc:"Add " > "%Dest:@=OTHERPROP%"
```

(untested, as I don't have your files or folderstructure)

Comment: Stephen - worked like a charm. Namaste. I adjusted code for my requirements with your code reference . somehow unable to format it here properly as always. i will learn that too :)  10k lines in fraction of second :) @ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET File=%AllActionScriptsMergedNotOrderedFile%

for %%A in ("add" "move" "insert" "changeprop") do (
  type %File% | findstr /b /i /c:"%%A" > "%FinalActionFolderName%\%%A_WorkFlows.txt"
)
type %File% |findstr /biv /c:"add" /biv /c:"Move" /biv /c:"insert" /biv /c:"changeprop"  > "%FinalActionFolderName%\OTHERPROP_WorkFlows.txt"

Comment: When you run it with `echo on` and examine the output, you will notice some "double double-quoting". Tip: take a deeper look at my code. I have one argument in quotes (because it contains a space) and later remove those quotes with `%%~a`. When you replace `%%A` with `%%~A` with the findstr command and within `"%FinalActionFolderName%\%%A_WorkFlows.txt"`, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, your syntax for `IF`/`ELSE` is incorrect. The general syntax is that there should always be a space before any opening code block parenthesis, whereas spaces following a closing code block parenthesis are not strictly problematic, even if technically not correct. `ELSE` is not an individual command, it is dependent upon `IF`, so it must be read in the same line.

Example based upon your latest provided code:

```bat
FOR /F "TOKENS=* DELIMS=" %%a IN ('TYPE "%File%"')DO (SET "eachline=%%a"
    IF /I "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD" (>>"%ADDActionScriptsMergedFile%" ECHO !eachline!
    )ELSE (IF /I "!eachline:~0,9!" == "ADDINSERT" (>>"%ADDINSERTActionScriptsMergedFile%" ECHO !eachline!
        )ELSE (IF /I "!eachline:~0,3!" == "MOV" (>>"%MOVEActionScriptsMergedFile%" ECHO !eachline!
            )ELSE (IF /I "!eachline:~0,6!" == "INSERT" (>>"%INSERTPROPActionScriptsMergedFile%" ECHO !eachline!
                )ELSE (IF /I "!eachline:~0,10!" == "CHANGEPROP" (>>"%CHANGEPROPActionScriptsMergedFile%" ECHO !eachline!
                    )ELSE >>"%OTHERPROPActionScriptsMergedFile%" ECHO !eachline!
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

*You'll note that I changed `IF /i "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD " (` to `IF /I "!eachline:~0,3!" == "ADD" (`, because I assumed it was a typo, (`"!eachline:~0,3!"` is always 3 characters, excluding the doublequotes, so it can never equal the four characters in `"ADD "`).